# What is the difference between Rf_dpois in Rmath.h and the dpois that I use directly in R?

Tags: r

If I see `Rmath.h` in `/usr/share/R/include`, the signature of the function `dpois` or `Rf_dpois` is

```
double dpois(double, double, int);
```

However, if I do `?dpois` in `R`, I see:

```
dpois(x, lambda, log = FALSE)
```

Are these both the same thing? If yes, can someone please clarify?

Also I tried to find the code for `dpois` at [R-svn](http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/stats/).

Can someone please tell how to find the code for functions like these?

Comment: I would like to preface the question by saying, I know I should have gone to r-help for questions like these. However, I know that some of the gurus are members of this forum as well. Also, I fear total destruction on r-help and r-dlevel for asking simple questions like these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes they are the same.  I am guessing that  `x` is double because of [type conversions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion). If `integer` is multiplied by `double` in C, the `double` is converted to integer. There are checks in the code that `x` is really integer, though it is of type `double`.

The code for this function is in `src/nmath/dpois.c`. I found it by doing `grep -R "dpois"` in directory with extracted R source code. This will work from the terminal in Linux and in Mac OS X. In Windows you will need to install grep. I suggest installing [Rtools](http://www.murdoch-sutherland.com/Rtools/index.html).

**Note.** The code is very short, but I intentionally do not post it here, since I do not know for sure if I will not break some licence by doing that.

Comment: Ok - so probably, I should have made it clearer, x is supposed to `integer`, right? Any specific reason it's double?

Comment: @suncoolsu, you are welcome.

Answer (score 5):

You could always test things, courtesy of [inline](http://cran.r-project.org/packages=inline) and [Rcpp](http://cran.r-project.org/packages=Rcpp).

Here we pass three lines of code to C++ to receive the two parameters, and then pass those to `Rf_dpois` (while setting the `log` argument to false):

```
R> library(Rcpp)
R> library(inline)
R> src <- "double x = Rcpp::as<double>(xs);
+         double y = Rcpp::as<double>(ys);
+         return(Rcpp::wrap(Rf_dpois(x, y, false)));"
R> fun <- cxxfunction(signature(xs="numeric",ys="numeric"), src, plugin = "Rcpp")
R> fun(2, 0.5)
[1] 0.0758163
R> dpois(2, 0.5)
[1] 0.0758163
R> fun(1.0, 0.5)
[1] 0.303265
R> dpois(1.0, 0.5)
[1] 0.303265
R>
```

The code to `dpois()` is in `R-2.12.1/src/nmath/dpois.c`. And yes, it can be freely copied.

Comment: Thanks. I was actually using Rf_dpois in a C++ program using `Rcpp` and testing it using `inline`. I have been been a user for about a week. But I very happy with the way I can test my C functions with `inline`. It turns out I am not smart enough to see this simple proof of concept. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

In reference to the question on how to find the source for headers of other functions, see this article in R News by Uwe Ligges:

Uwe Ligges. R Help Desk: [Accessing the sources](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2006-4.pdf). R News, 6(4):43-45, October 2006.